# changing the phpmyadmin default url

Tags: linux, apache, phpmyadmin, centos

I am wondering how to change the default URL for phpMyAdmin. I am using the latest version (4.0.4.1) on my CentOS 6 VPS. I am wanting to change it from /phpmyadmin to something more secure. I am unsure how to do this or where to even find my apache.conf file if there is one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

For ubuntu (i used ubuntu 12.04), the default phpmyadmin apache configuration can be found at  `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf`

You can open it by type `sudo nano /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf` and change the third

```
Alias /yournewalias /usr/share/phpmyadmin
```

Do not forget to restart apache service,

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 5):

**phpMyAdmin default Apache configuration**

> Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin

Change that to

**phpMyAdmin default Apache configuration**

> Alias /anyname /usr/share/phpmyadmin

Then make sure to restart Apache

> sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

Answer (score 0):

Edit this file

```
/etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf
```

line 3: change the line to be

```
Alias /whateveryouwant /usr/share/phpmyadmin
```