# Amazon EC2 hide phpmyadmin route

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin, instance

I am hosting my web app on Amazon EC2 and I'm struggling how to hide the phpMyAdmin route from being accessable. My database and web app are on the same instance and I don't want others to access it. If there it is possible i would like to access it through some other route instead of /phpmyadmin, for example /sampleroute.

Thanks :)

Comment: see [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17403621/changing-the-phpmyadmin-default-url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17403621/changing-the-phpmyadmin-default-url) may help

Comment: Thanks ... this helped me :)